# How to log app run time

Tags: applications, logging

Long story short, I need to log these things some apps: The starting time of the app, total running time and the end time of the app.

**Edit: I would want to run this a whole week, to see how much time these apps are using**
.

Comment: Tasker is a good candidate for this.

Comment: @xavier_fakerat Well Tasker seems like overkill for me but I'll try, does it require root?

Comment: Not really, only needs to be enabled in accessibility services, besides this particular project doesn't need any elevated privileges. Two key things fr this task: set a variable with day, time for both start and end task then you need the "write file" action in both tasks , I recommend to use .csv file (better presentability).

Comment: @xavier_fakerat Could you please assist me with this process? I'm kind of having some problems with figuring that

Comment: @user218893 Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! I've slightly rephrased your question – as asking for apps (or other off-site resources) is off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic) and [Where to ask for app recommendations?](/q/2060/16575)). Should solve your intention nevertheless: if there is a way to do it with the stuff that already is on your device, you'd certainly accept that as well if you knew hot to use it, right? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround you could use.

Objective: Create a Task make an application runtime log.

**Profile**

Application >> Select target application e.g Facebook app (Tap back to exit out of this profile.

Long press the first context and select Add >> Day >> Select number of days e.g 7 days

**Tasks**

**Task 1 (entrance) You can name it Facebook login time or anything.**

1. A1 Variables>> Variable Set [Name: %Logintime to %DATE %TIME (leave everythin as is)]

Tap back to perform second action.

2. File >> Write File >> [File (give any name e.g sd_card/Facebook logtime.csv) Text (Start, %Logintime) Tick Append, Tick Add New line]

   Save and exit this Task

Create another task

**Task 2 (exit) You can name it Facebook logout time or anything.**

1. A1 Variables>> Variable Set [Name: %Logouttime to %DATE %TIME (leave everythin as is)]

Tap back to perform second action.

2. File >> Write File >> [File (give any name e.g sd_card/Facebook logtime.csv) Text (Start, %Logouttime) Tick Append, Tick Add New line]

Save and exit this Task

*Explanation: When the Facebook application is opened, the log file (that .csv file you created) is written the start time, and when you exit it writes again the end time, such that after a week it shows time you used the facebook app, hence you can calculate the time.*

Please note, to perform calculations within tasker is possible but is advanced so I just did it the simple way.

Happy logging!